# Can windows override BIOS fan speed settings?

Tags: windows-10, bios, fan

I get this problem (seems like after windows 10 update) - when windows loads it takes all case fans to 1200+ RPM and it is very loud. However, I have set settings in BIOS for fans (only case fans, not CPU fan or other) to be in "Silent" mode with control via voltage (they are 3-pin connectors). And in BIOS RPM is in 600-800 range which is completely OK. But when I boot windows, they start going very loud at 1200+ RPM (as shown by AIDA64).

[Gigabyte Smart Fan 5 BIOS settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OAsY.jpg)

Can this be windows problem? Can I fix this? (preferably without any side software)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The easy way to see if its a "Windows" problem is to live boot Linux off a USB stick and see if it does the same. If so, it's likely that your heat paste on your CPU is expiring, driving up the temperature and causing your fans to spin up to max - your CPU isn't really doing much while in the BIOS, so are unlikely to spin up there.

If it is indeed a Windows problem, you can most certainly fix it with the right settings or software, try starting at your official motherboard support page download section (https://www.gigabyte.com/Support/Motherboard), and see if there is any motherboard utility available for download - also make sure it's your motherboard fans and not your GPU fans, as they are separate.